# Swift UITableViewCell not showing Labels

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to create a custom cell view with some labels, I have created a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and connected the labels to it. Inside `cellForRowAt` method I dequeued the cell and cast it as `YourCell` subclass to access the labels and set text.

[Setting class of cell to `YourCell`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmxZX.png)

However when running the app, nothing is showing up.

```
class YourCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    let array1 = ["Name1", "Name2","Name3","Name3"]
    let array2 = ["1","2","3","4"]
    let array3 = ["18","17","11","9"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! YourCell
        cell.label1.text = array1[indexPath.row]
        cell.label2.text = array2[indexPath.row]
        cell.label3.text = array3[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array2.count
    }


}
```

Comment: You’ve set tableview .delegate but you also need to setup its .dataSource

Comment: Unrelated but multiple arrays as data source is a horrible practice. Don't do that.

Comment: The cell is inside a custom xib or inside the storyboard?

Comment: @vadian Those are just test arrays :)

Comment: @Kamil.S You're right, silly mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have conformed the UITableViewDelegate protocol correctly, the only thing you are missing is to set up your datasource by including this line in your viewDidLoad.

```
tableview.dataSource = self
```